# Symfony 3.4 and PHP Version

Tags: php, symfony

I'm taking over a project under Symfony 3.4.

I have an error related to the version of php I guess :

```
ContextErrorException
in vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php (line 2636)
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
```

So I created a .php-version file with "7.2" inside.

But when I do a

```
php bin\console about
```

I have the php version in 7.3.5.

I have tried also to change my php version in Env variable path of windows 10 and in wamp, but even after a reboot, a

```
php -v
```

show a 7.3.5 version.

An idea to force the php version that my Symfony app must use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This warning clearly states that you have `switch` with `case ###: continue` inside. It's not related with PHP version, just fix it or suppress warnings (Don't). Also to change PHP version you must actually re-install different version of PHP, not just change some strings in config

Comment: This warning message was added to PHP 7.3 to highlight/clarify a way in which PHP's `continue` statement works differently to similar syntax in other languages. If you're getting it after an upgrade to 7.3 in a third-party lib like Symfony or Doctrine then I would suggest the first thing to do is consider updating the versions of third party libs. Products like Symfony and Doctrine are on the ball re PHP versions and will definitely have picked up warnings of this type and addressed them by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple php versions installed in multiple directories and you wish to use a certain php version on the command line you need to specify which php to use, and which php.ini to use.

For command line(CMD):

```
C:\php7.1\php.exe -c C:\php7.1\php.ini bin\console about
```

[git for windows bash](https://gitforwindows.org/)

```
/c/php7.1/php.exe -c /c/php7.1/php.ini bin/console about
```

For your wamp server you need to define which php version to use via the httpd.conf or the other config files you may use.

I need to run some things on 5.6 to be able to check back old sites and for that I use to get it working on my dev machine.

```
ScriptAlias /php/ "C:/php-5.6.9-Win32-VC11-x64/"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
#SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR "C:/php-5.6.9-Win32-VC11-x64/"
SetEnv PHPRC "C:/php-5.6.9-Win32-VC11-x64/"
Action application/x-httpd-php "/php/php-cgi.exe"
```